Power Query code to refer to another query (and how buffering works)
I am trying to reuse a power query to pull information from another power query.  It seems like there are multiple way of doing this.  I see two ways of doing this from this question.  I also see it in my own spreadsheets.  In my spread sheet I apparently have:
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Project_List"]}[Content],

In other queries I have:
Source = Project_List,

Is there an advantage to one method or the other?
Ultimately what I am hoping to achieve is to query the data once across the network, dump it into a table A then in follow up queries keep referring to table A and not pull the data across the network for the subsequent queries.
I noticed that when I was building my most recent query using the Source = Project_List,,  at each step of the follow up query it was loading actually reloaded all the files that Project_list query loads.
Is this just part of the building process?  Or If I have one query A that loads across the network and 5 follow up queries that refer to query A will power query / excel be reading the across the network 1 time or five times?
What is the proper way in Power Query to refer to an existing query and reduce data pulls across the network?

Power Query will always stream data from source - see here for a fuller understanding.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIvneMAE50o
The only way around this is to use Table.Buffer or List.Buffer to temporarily cache the data.
For this line, then presumably you have another query named Project_List which in turn gets your data from the workbook?
Source = Project_List,


Exactly,  Project_List is a table that is a result of another PQ

In that case, there is no difference between your two options at the beginning of your question. Ultimately, they will both stream from the source

Currently listening to this 1 hour long Youtube video.  Its over my head but I did catch the table.buffer .  That and "Order matters".   I am going to ask a followup question on on Table.Buffering.

It can be quite a bit to take in but Ben is the authority on this stuff. This is a good reference: https://bengribaudo.com/power-query-m-primer

I think my question comes up in the post presentation discussion at the 48:28 mark.  And so far from what I understand in the answer is that Table.Buffer only helps within the one query and will be be rebuffered on subsequent query calls.

I'm not sure that's actually right. I'll update my answer to include a test you can do.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If you want to test buffering queries, you can try this. Query A is
let
 Source = {1..1e1},
 #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
 #"Added to Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table", {{"Column1", each _ + Number.Random(), type number}}),
 A = Table.Buffer(#"Added to Column")
in
 A

and B is
 let
 Source = {1..1e1},
 #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
 BufferedA = Table.Buffer(A), 
 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Custom", each A),
 #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1"}, {"Custom.Column1"})
in
 #"Expanded Custom"

You can test 3 ways - no buffer, buffer in B and buffer in A. No buffer is random always, whilst buffer in A or B is cached and repeated
Right click and create a blank query:


going to feel like a bit of an idiot with this question.  how do you create a power query in excel from scratch when you have no source?

I'll update the answer now.

Entered both the queries. ("Query1" and "Query2" were the default names).  When I entered Query2 with a cut and paste of the m code provided above, I get and Expression.Error: THe import A matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference? error.  I also tried renaming Query1 to A but it said error variabl ein use or something to that effect

The code is fine. You need to rename A before you create the second query. Delete your second query, rename the first to "A" and then recreate your second query
